# How to delete keys from multi-dimension array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to filter this array to see only future items.
How do I unset items from which the timeEnd has expired?
i.e when I call this array at 17:00 there's only array[2] left.

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3034
            [date] => 28-09-2016
            [timeStart] => 08:30
            [timeEnd] => 09:30
            [description] => User_A
            [locationId] => 1
            [roomId] => 8
            [relationId] => 104
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2524
        [date] => 28-09-2016
        [timeStart] => 08:30
        [timeEnd] => 12:00
        [description] => User_B
        [locationId] => 1
        [roomId] => 5
        [relationId] => 86
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2533
        [date] => 28-09-2016
        [timeStart] => 09:00
        [timeEnd] => 18:00
        [description] => User_C
        [locationId] => 1
        [roomId] => 4
        [relationId] => 31
    )
```

)

Comment: loop through the array create timestamp from date + timeEnd keys then compare with current time and if time > calculatedtime unset the current index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($reservations as $key=>$reservation) {
    $expireDate = $reservation['date'].' '.$reservation['timeEnd'];
    if (strtotime($expireDate) <= strtotime('now')){
        unset($reservations[$key]);
    }
}
```